# Unable to Process Data from Text File in C++

Tags: c++, database, text-files

Why is it that this program will not register the correct ID and Pin number entered?

Anything typed will proceed to wrong data being input but the correct data doesn't get recognized.

Inside the text file is 5 IDs, and 5 Pin numbers in a format of 5 rows 2 columns.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    const int MAX=10, screenWidth=80;
    string A = "Welcome to ABC Bank!";
    int i=0;
    int ID[MAX], Password[MAX], pin, acc, counter=1 ,limit=2;
    cout<<setw((screenWidth-A.size())/2)<<" "<<A<<endl;
    cout<<"\nAccount ID: ";
    cin>>acc;
    cout<<"Pin: ";
    cin>>pin;

    ifstream accountFile;
    accountFile.open("AccountDetails.txt");

    if (!accountFile)
        cout<<"Unable to open requested file!";
    else
    {
        while (!accountFile.eof())
        {
            accountFile>>ID[i]>>Password[i];
            i++;
        }

        accountFile.close();

        while (acc==ID[i] && pin==Password[i])
        {
            cout<<"Login successful!\n";
            break;
        }

        while (acc!=ID[i] || pin!=Password[i])
        {
            if (counter==3)
            {
                cout<<"\nUnauthorized Access Detected. Account has been LOCKED!\n";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\nWrong Account ID/Pin. Please try again!"<<" (Attempts Left:"<<limit<<")";
                cout<<"\nAccount ID: ";
                cin>>acc;
                cout<<"Pin: ";
                cin>>pin;
                counter++;
                limit--;
            }
        }   
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

After reviewing what @Joachim Pileborg stated in his answer earlier,
this is the updated code that I have done. Sadly, now this code fails to login successfully after the 1st attempt fails and the 2nd attempt is correct.

```
ifstream accountFile;
accountFile.open("AccountDetails.txt");

if (!accountFile)
    cout<<"Unable to open requested file!";
else
{
    while (accountFile>>ID[i]>>Password[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    accountFile.close();

    bool success = false;
    for (int j=0; !success && j<i; j++)
    {
        if (ID[j] == acc && Password[j] == pin)
            success = true; 
    }
    if (success)
        cout<<"\nLogin Successful!\n";
    else
    {
        while (!success)
        {
            cout<<"\nAccount ID/Pin is incorrect. Please try again!"<<" (Attempts Left: "<<limit<<" )";
            cout<<"\nAccount ID: ";
            cin>>acc;
            cout<<"Pin: ";
            cin>>pin;
            counter++;
            limit--;
            if (counter==3)
            {
                cout<<"Unauthorized Access Detected! Account Has Been LOCKED!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}           
system("pause");
```

Comment: Don't do e.g. `while (!some_stream.eof()) { ... }`, it will it almost all cases not work as expected. Instead in your case simply do `while (accountFile>>ID[i]>>Password[i]) { ++i; }`. Remember to check `i` afterwards to see if anything was read at all. You might also want to add a check to make sure the file doesn't contain more entries than your arrays (or start using e.g. `std::vector` for "dynamic arrays").

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Vector has yet to be taught so I am highly uncertain of how to use vector in this scenario. How do you check for [ i ] to see if any data was read at all in my case?

Comment: After the reading loop, if nothing was read and `i` never increased, what do you think the value of `i` would be?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If [ i ] never increased, [ i ]'s value would still be at 0 since i declared it to be zero. However, won't it increase since I coded it to be [ i++;]?

Comment: If the file is empty, and you make the fix I suggested in my first comment, then the increment will never happen and `i` will still be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for your login success/failure checks are flawed. To begin with they will invoke *undefined behavior* because you will access uninitialized elements of the arrays.

If, as you say, the file contains five entries, then after the loop `i` will have the value `5` which is the *sixth* element in the arrays (after you fix the reading loop, otherwise the value of `i` will be `6`).

If we then overlook the UB (Undefined Behavior) the first loop, checking for successful login, that condition will most likely *never* be true, and that's good because otherwise you would have an infinite loop there. Then comes the second loop where you check for unsuccessful login, where the condition will almost *always* be true, and that will lead to an infinite loop.

To check if the login credentials given by the user was correct or not, I suggest something like

```
bool success = false;

for (int j = 0; !success && j < i; ++j)
{
    if (ID[j] == acc && Password[j] == pin)
    {
        success = true;
    }
}

if (success)
{
    // Login successful
}
else
{
    // Login failed
}
```

Comment: For this, the fail part doesn't loop and I cannot initialize the attempts counter. Because the else is not in the for/while loop, even after typing in the correct data, it will login successfully, but if you type the wrong one the first time, the second time you type in the wrong data, it does not allow you to loop and try again. It straight away goes to system("pause") in my case...

Comment: @SmallLittleIntrovert Just nest the shown code in another loop, and you have your retry-loop (remember to break out of it in the "login successful" case).

Comment: I have re-edited the code as you stated. Is it something like this? The code has been posted back in my question.

Comment: Sadly, now the code doesn't process anything that is correct after a failed attempt :( Where did i go wrong again to fail the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
const int MAX=10, screenWidth=80;
string A = "Welcome to ABC Bank!";
int i=0;
int ID[MAX], Password[MAX], pin, acc, counter=1 ,limit=2;
cout<<setw((screenWidth-A.size())/2)<<" "<<A<<endl;
cout<<"\nAccount ID: ";
cin>>acc;
cout<<"Pin: ";
cin>>pin;

ifstream accountFile;
accountFile.open("AccountDetails.txt");

if (!accountFile)
    cout<<"Unable to open requested file!";
else
{
    while (accountFile>>ID[i]>>Password[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    accountFile.close();

    bool success = false;
    while (!success)
    {
    for (int j=0; !success && j<i; j++)
    {
        if (ID[j] == acc && Password[j] == pin)
            success = true; 
    }
    if (success)
        cout<<"\nLogin Successful!\n";
    else
    {           
        cout<<"\nAccount ID/Pin is incorrect. Please try again!"<<" (Attempts Left: "<<limit<<" )";
        cout<<"\nAccount ID: ";
        cin>>acc;
        cout<<"Pin: ";
        cin>>pin;
        counter++;
        limit--;            
    }
    if (counter==4)
        {
            cout<<"Unauthorized Access Detected! Account Has Been LOCKED!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}           
system("pause");
}
```

CODE IS WORKING, Thank you for the input and help Mr Joachim Pileborg!